# EncFS: Trying to create folder in a folder results in permission error

Tags: debian, fuse

I have an server where I want to encrypt some data for protection

so usualy I do

```
sudo encfs /folder/encrypted /folder/unencrypted -o allow_other
```

When I then later try to (using a normal user) create a folder or file in the root of /folder/encrypted it works, but if i later on try to create a folder or file within my newly created folder I get permission error

Doing ls -l shows root is owner of created folders/files in /folder/unencrypted

Never dealt with Fuse or EncFS before and good old mighty Goodle couldn't awnser either so..

In the long run I plan to have multiply users with different usergroups accessing this share, and all of them should be able to write and read

Answer (score 0):

Using the flag --public solves this, so awnsering my own question the command to mount a EncFS would be:

```
sudo encfs --public /folder/encrypted /folder/unencrypted
```

More information in the man pages: http://linux.die.net/man/1/encfs

FYI: This give **everyone** read/write permissions to the unencrypted folder